# How do I prevent MySQL from updating column with empty string?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I have a form to update details of a user and they do not have to fill in every field. Because of that, it will be passing an empty string to the database via POST. This is my query:

```
$q = "UPDATE mdl_user SET firstname='$fname', lastname='$lname', email='$email',
      address='$address', city='$city', school='$school', phone1='$phone'
      WHERE id='$uid'";
```

Is there a way for MySQL to check if for example `$fname` is an empty string and if it's empty don't update that field?

If not then how should I go about doing this in PHP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use IF statement for each field you need to check. For example :

```
$q = "UPDATE mdl_user SET firstname=IF(LENGTH('$fname')=0, firstname, '$fname'), lastname=IF(LENGTH('$lname')=0, lastname, '$lname'), email=IF(LENGTH('$email')=0, email, '$email'), address='$address', city='$city', school='$school', phone1='$phone' WHERE id='$uid'";
```

Comment: Hey, cheers. Can you explain what the second and third parameters in the IF clause means?

Comment: Hi. IF(<YOUR_CONDITION>, <VALUE_IF_TRUE>, <VALUE_IF_FALSE>). So if string length=0 then don't change it.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this

```
<?php
if ($fname) {
 $fname = "firstname='$fname',";
} else {
 $fname = '';
}
$q = "UPDATE mdl_user SET $fname lastname='$lname', email='$email', address='$address', city='$city', school='$school', phone1='$phone' WHERE id='$uid'";
?>
```

But you should really be worried about how insecure your code is.

Comment: Insecure? Are you sure? How do you know he's not escaping each of those variables?

Comment: One can assume these variables are properly sanitized after collection from the form. I hope ?
The empty string will just add nothing to the QUERY, and since the column name is in it, it won't update it in the DB.

Comment: I hate to be rude, and no offence should be taken because we have all been there, but with a question this primative one could assume that he is not escaping.

Comment: @user1219572 It would not because you are taking out the whole assignment, it can either be a whole value, or nothing, note that the sql has had the firstname= part removed

Comment: Can you suggest any other ways because your code would imply that I would have to do an if statement for every single input? :/

Comment: @user1219572, why do programmers complain about typing? :) But check out Alex's answer too.

Comment: @user1219572 If that needs to be done on all of your values, then I would go with Alex's answer also.

Answer (score -2):

First run a **SELECT** statement and do a **mysql_num_row()** if this returns a value **>0** then **exit()**

Comment: Select statement for what? :/ I just want to make sure I don't update a column with an empty string and thus overwriting any previous values in that column