# Prevent MySQL from updating column with empty string?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

Found this answer [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737752/how-do-i-prevent-mysql-from-updating-column-with-empty-string), however I have about 100 inputs that need updating.

I currently have this code for cleaning up the values:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
$data[$key] = filter($value);}
```

Can I add the answer from the above link to this code to affect all 100 inputs or would I be forced to add the IF clause on each input.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$update_arr = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (strlen($value) !== 0)
    {
        $update_arr[] = $key.' = "'.filter($value).'"';
    }
}
$update_string = implode(',',$update_arr);
$table = '';
$where = '';

$format = "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s";
$sql = sprintf($format,$table,$update_string,$where);
```

Comment: I updated to the following :<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit')  
{
$update_arr = array();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    if (strlen($value) !== 0)
    {
        $update_arr[] = $key.' = "'.filter($value).'"';
    }
}
$update_string = implode(',',$update_arr);
$table = '';
$where = '';

$format = "UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE %s";
$sql = sprintf($format,$table,$update_string,$where);
mysql_query(" UPDATE `labor`
    SET 
    labor_status='$data[labor_status]',
    labor_type=IF(LENGTH('$data[labor_type]')=0,labor_type,} ... etc. and nothing is entered into the database.

Comment: Check to see what the generated query is. If the SQL syntax is correct, then you have either a db connection error, or you have a problem with the actual code to execute the command.