# How do I prevent MySQL from updating column with an empty string using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the exact question as [How do I prevent MySQL from updating column with an empty string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737752/how-do-i-prevent-mysql-from-updating-column-with-empty-string)

However, the only twist is that I am applying this to PDO instead of the conventional MySQL.

I have followed the top answer on that question regarding adding IF statements to check if the length is 0. This does not seem to work for PDO however since no update occurs into the table and the webpage outputs: `Array ( [0] => HY093 [1] => [2] => ) 1`. Note I am using prepared statements via the bind function.

My PHP code with the IF statement included:

```
    <?php
$pdo=new PDO("mysql:dbname=createyo_TestDatabase;host=localhost","createyo_james","password");

$statement=$pdo->prepare(
"UPDATE `Users` 
SET `EditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':EditID')=0, EditIDs, ':EditID'), 
`ArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':ArticleID')=0, ArticleIDs, ':ArticleID'),
`Reputation` = IF(LENGTH(':Reputation')=0, Reputation, ':Reputation'),
`VotedUpArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':VotedUpArticleID')=0, VotedUpArticleIDs, ':VotedUpArticleID'),
`VotedUpEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':VotedUpEditID')=0, VotedUpEditIDs, ':VotedUpEditID'),
`VotedDownArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':VotedDownArticleID')=0, VotedDownArticleIDs, ':VotedDownArticleID'),
`VotedDownEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(':VotedDownEditID')=0, VotedDownEditIDs, ':VotedDownEditID'),
WHERE `UserID` = :UserID");

$statement->bindValue(':EditID', (string) trim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':ArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['ArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':Reputation', (string) trim($_GET['Reputation']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpEditID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownEditID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $statement->bindValue(':UserID', (string) trim($_GET['UserID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $statement->execute() or die(print_r($statement->errorInfo()));
$results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$json=json_encode($results);
print $json;
?>
```

**Edit**

I am now receiving a syntax error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `UserID` = '1234'' at line 9. I have not been able to understand this error.

New PHP code:

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare(
"UPDATE `Users` 
SET `EditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:EditID)=0, EditIDs, :EditID1), 
`ArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:ArticleID)=0, ArticleIDs, :ArticleID1),
`Reputation` = IF(LENGTH(:Reputation)=0, Reputation, :Reputation1),
`VotedUpArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpArticleID)=0, VotedUpArticleIDs, :VotedUpArticleID1),
`VotedUpEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpEditID)=0, VotedUpEditIDs, :VotedUpEditID1),
`VotedDownArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownArticleID)=0, VotedDownArticleIDs, :VotedDownArticleID1),
`VotedDownEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownEditID)=0, VotedDownEditIDs, :VotedDownEditID1),
WHERE `UserID` = :UserID");
$statement->bindValue(':EditID', (string) trim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':ArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['ArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $statement->bindValue(':Reputation', (string) trim($_GET['Reputation']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpEditID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownArticleID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownEditID', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);

$statement->bindValue(':EditID1', (string) trim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':ArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['ArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':Reputation1', (string) trim($_GET['Reputation']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpEditID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownEditID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error HY093 with a MySQL Insert PDO Request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027112/error-hy093-with-a-mysql-insert-pdo-request)

Comment: You have a comma immediately before the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the SQL, you should not put `:placeholder` inside quotes. That makes them into literal strings, so they won't get substituted from the bound parameters.

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare(
"UPDATE `Users` 
SET `EditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:EditID)=0, EditIDs, :EditID), 
`ArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:ArticleID)=0, ArticleIDs, :ArticleID),
`Reputation` = IF(LENGTH(:Reputation)=0, Reputation, :Reputation),
`VotedUpArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpArticleID)=0, VotedUpArticleIDs, :VotedUpArticleID),
`VotedUpEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpEditID)=0, VotedUpEditIDs, :VotedUpEditID),
`VotedDownArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownArticleID)=0, VotedDownArticleIDs, :VotedDownArticleID),
`VotedDownEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownEditID)=0, VotedDownEditIDs, :VotedDownEditID),
WHERE `UserID` = :UserID");
```

However, you're also not allowed to use the same `:placeholder` multiple times in the same query. So you'll need to give the repeated placeholders different names.

```
$statement=$pdo->prepare(
"UPDATE `Users` 
SET `EditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:EditID)=0, EditIDs, :EditID1), 
`ArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:ArticleID)=0, ArticleIDs, :ArticleID1),
`Reputation` = IF(LENGTH(:Reputation)=0, Reputation, :Reputation1),
`VotedUpArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpArticleID)=0, VotedUpArticleIDs, :VotedUpArticleID1),
`VotedUpEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedUpEditID)=0, VotedUpEditIDs, :VotedUpEditID1),
`VotedDownArticleIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownArticleID)=0, VotedDownArticleIDs, :VotedDownArticleID1),
`VotedDownEditIDs` = IF(LENGTH(:VotedDownEditID)=0, VotedDownEditIDs, :VotedDownEditID1)
WHERE `UserID` = :UserID");
```

Then you'll have to bind all the additional parameters:

```
$statement->bindValue(':EditID1', (string) trim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':ArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['ArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':Reputation', (string) trim($_GET['Reputation']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedUpEditID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedUpEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownArticleID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownArticleID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':VotedDownEditID1', (string) trim($_GET['VotedDownEditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I was looking for. However, I am now receiving a syntax error for the WHERE part of the query. I have updated the question.

Comment: You have an extra comma at the end of the `VotedDownEditIDs` line.

Comment: Thanks :) I should really use a proper PHP IDE instead of the one the web hosts give me.

Answer (score 0):

Have your own `trim` function like

```
  function nulltrim($str)
  {
      $s = trim($str);
      if ( empty($s) ) 
            return null;
      return $s;
  }
```

and

```
  $statement->bindValue(':EditID', (string) nulltrim($_GET['EditID']), PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

should solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Does this mean to say the IF statement I used does not work for PDO or is this just a method you find more suitable?

Comment: you're updating the column with it's current value. If that's already an empty string, this will stay and not converted to `null` obviously.